# How to associate point to nearest state boundary outside of the state the point is in

Tags: r, distance, sp, borders, closest-distance

I have a point within a state and I want to find 1) the distance to the nearest state border and 2) the bordering state's name. I am able to do 1). For 2). I am able to get the state name corresponding to the nearest boundary, *but sometimes this state is the state the point is in, and not actually the bordering state's name.*

Modifying and extending the code from an excellent answer of this post ([Calculate distance between points and nearest polygon in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225102/calculate-distance-between-points-and-nearest-polygon-in-r)), I do:

```
library(sp)
library(spData)
library(tidyverse)

states <- as(us_states,"Spatial")
    
#create some points
pts <- data.frame(x1=c(-100.5, -98.6, -98), x2=c(35, 41, 44))

# compute the shortest distance between points and polygons
# (from ?dist2Line): "returns matrix with distance and lon/lat of the nearest point" & 
# "the ID (index) of (one of) the nearest objects"; distance is in meters (default)
dist.mat <- geosphere::dist2Line(p = pts, line = states)

# bind results with original points
pts.wit.dist <- cbind(pts, dist.mat)
pts.wit.dist[1:3,]

pts.sp <- sp::SpatialPoints(coords      = pts[,c("x1","x2")], # order matters
                            proj4string = states@proj4string)
plot(pts.sp, col="red")
plot(states, add=TRUE)

# plot arrows to indicate the direction of the great-circle-distance
for (i in 1:nrow(pts.wit.dist)) {
    arrows(x0 = pts.wit.dist[i,1], 
           y0 = pts.wit.dist[i,2], 
           x1 = pts.wit.dist[i,4], 
           y1 = pts.wit.dist[i,5],
           length = 0.1,
           col = "green")
}

a <- pts.wit.dist
a <- a %>% mutate(miles = distance*0.000621)

#create crosswalk between ID (from dist2Line) and state name (from state shapefile)
state_names <- data.frame(us_states$NAME) %>% mutate(ID=row_number())
names(state_names)[1] <- "state"

b <- left_join(pts.wit.dist, state_names, by="ID")

b
```

This produces:

```
> b
      x1 x2  distance        lon      lat ID        state
1 -100.5 35  45558.45 -100.00039 35.00162 23        Texas
2  -98.6 41 110992.87  -98.59800 40.00294 37     Nebraska
3  -98.0 44 118342.74  -98.49855 42.99856 22 South Dakota
```

[image]

However, the `state` is incorrect in all cases. It should be:

```
> b
      x1 x2  distance        lon      lat ID        state
1 -100.5 35  45558.45 -100.00039 35.00162 23        Oklahoma
2  -98.6 41 110992.87  -98.59800 40.00294 37     Kansas
3  -98.0 44 118342.74  -98.49855 42.99856 22 Nebraska
```

It's tricky because the borders obviously are borders between two states, and I am not sure how to make it give me the state that is not the one in which the point is contained.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you have to drop the state the point is in from the search set - imagine a point near the california coast - without dropping california from the search set the shortest distance will be to the coast, and not (say) to a point on the CA-NV border so you could identify it as having NV as the nearest other state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point of view, your problem can be seen as a nearest neighbour search using points and polygons, considering the condition to exclude the state your current point is located. My take making use of `sf` and `nngeo`:

```r
library(sf)
library(nngeo)

# create sf objects with same crs -> WGS 84
states <- us_states |> st_transform(st_crs(4326))

pts <- data.frame(x = c(-100.5, -98.6, -98), 
                  y = c(35, 41, 44)) |> st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)

# init empty list
results <- list(states = list(),
                distances = list())

for (i in 1:dim(pts)[1]) {
  
  # select current point
  pt <- pts[i, ]
  state_pt <- states[pt, ]
  
  # which neighbours to consider? exlude state containing pt first
  n_states <- dplyr::filter(states, NAME != state_pt[["NAME"]])
  
  # determine nn
  result <- nngeo::st_nn(pt, n_states, k = 1, returnDist = TRUE)
  
  # return nn state and corresponding distance to the border
  results[["states"]][[i]] <- n_states[result[["nn"]] |> unlist(), ]
  results[["distances"]][[i]] <- result[["dist"]] |> unlist()
}

results
#> $states
#> $states[[1]]
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 6 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -103.0024 ymin: 33.63787 xmax: -94.43122 ymax: 37.0001
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>    GEOID     NAME REGION            AREA total_pop_10 total_pop_15
#> 19    40 Oklahoma  South 180971.4 [km^2]      3675339      3849733
#>                          geometry
#> 19 MULTIPOLYGON (((-103.0022 3...
#> 
#> $states[[2]]
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 6 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -102.0517 ymin: 36.99308 xmax: -94.60703 ymax: 40.00308
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>   GEOID   NAME  REGION            AREA total_pop_10 total_pop_15
#> 9    20 Kansas Midwest 213037.1 [km^2]      2809329      2892987
#>                         geometry
#> 9 MULTIPOLYGON (((-102.0517 4...
#> 
#> $states[[3]]
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 6 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -104.0532 ymin: 40 xmax: -95.30829 ymax: 43.00078
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>    GEOID     NAME  REGION            AREA total_pop_10 total_pop_15
#> 36    31 Nebraska Midwest 200272.3 [km^2]      1799125      1869365
#>                          geometry
#> 36 MULTIPOLYGON (((-104.0531 4...
#> 
#> 
#> $distances
#> $distances[[1]]
#> [1] 45507.54
#> 
#> $distances[[2]]
#> [1] 110868.8
#> 
#> $distances[[3]]
#> [1] 118392.9
```

Et voilà - Oklahoma, Kansas, Nebraska with distances attached should be your desired output.

Comment: Thanks @falk-env! Is there a way to also return the distance between the point and the nearest neighbor state border?

Comment: Yeah, there actually is making use of `nngeo::st_nn(..., returnDist = TRUE)`. I edited my answer to consider this. By the way, distances are given in meters.

Comment: Thank you! This is great.